# How do you read in this json array?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "1370" : ["Tomai", "Grabowski", "Chebotko", "Egle"],
    "2380" : ["Schweller", "Chen", "Tomai"],
    "3333" : ["Schweller", "Chen", "The Devil"]
}
```

I would assume that you would access say chebotko by 1370[2] but it isn't giving me anything. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I am accessing it.

```
$.getJSON("instructors.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1370` is a property of the object. The object itself needs to be referenced in some kind of variable. `var myObject = { '1370': ... }`, or if it's a response from an AJAX request, you'll access that as an input parameter to your callback function. Either way, you need to first reference the object itself, then its properties:

```
alert(myObject['1370'][2]) // 'Chebotko'
```

Comment: I am trying to get it from a file that I put in the same directory called instructor.json and that text is all that is inside it. I can change it if need be but I notice my console recongizes it but only as Ojbect. If I add var professor = to it, it won't work.

Comment: @MarlinHankin: As you're saying in your updated question, `data` is the reference to the object. That's the variable name you want to use. `alert(data['1370'][2])`.